# Respect Validation Optional Key

Tags: php, respect-validation

Sometimes users can send some missing key/value pairs. So in that situation I need to validate optional keys if they exists.

User biography is an optional field. If user leaves it empty I don't want it to be posted.

```
v::key('biography', v::optional(v::stringType()->length(10, 1000)))
```

Abode code validates if biography is not null or empty, if posted object does not contain biography key it raise exception, because validator expect biography. I couldn't find the way to check "if the key exists continue validation chain"; I can add not existing keys into the posted data before validation but I believe there is a better way to do this in the library.

I am looking a solution that should like this:

```
v::key('biography', v::keyExist(v::optional(v::stringType()->length(10, 1000))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of Key states:

> Third parameter makes the key presence optional:
>
> `v::key('lorem', v::stringType(), false)->validate($dict); // true`

That said, if "lorem" does not exists, Validation won't apply the StringType validation.

See: http://respect.github.io/Validation/docs/key.html

Comment: Yes if Lorem does not exist it throws error, but I don’t want it to raise error when it not exists. I want validation to validate if it exists other wise continue rest validation chains

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OneOf](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/1.1/docs/OneOf.md) validator for your case.

```
$response = v::key('biography', v::oneOf(
    v::stringType()->length(10, 1000),
    v::nullType()
))->validate($author);
```

If you try to validate this value:

```
$author = [];
```

or this one:

```
$author = [
    'biography' => 'testtesttest'
];
```

you'll get `true`, otherwise if you try to validate this one:

```
$author = [
    'biography' => 'small'
];
```

you'll get `false` (string length is not between 10 and 1000).

Comment: I realize this is a pretty old question and answer, but the above does not work for me. I'm still seeing an exception thrown saying the key must be present.

Comment: I figured it out. v::key has an optional third argument called `mandatory` that can be set to false. This allowed me to validate the value if present, but ignore it and not raise an error if it's missing.